# Haskell No Parse

Tags: haskell

I'm getting a "no parse" error when I test these functions (with input of ordinary integers) and I don't know why. What am I doing wrong here?

```
lastLetter :: String -> String
lastLetter (l:[]) = [l]
lastLetter (l:ls) = lastLetter(ls)

lastDigit :: Integer -> Integer
lastDigit = read . lastLetter . show
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce, works as expected on my GHCi. Could you post the whole error message?

Comment: btw: your `lastLetter` is just `return . last` and indeed `read . return . last $ show 1234 :: Integer` should work like a charm (the `:: Integer` is important - if you remove it you'll get your mentioned error)

Comment: For this particular use case, consider using modular arithmetic instead of formatting and reparsing the integer: `lastDigit = abs . flip rem 10`.